# How to create infinit Iframe containing itself page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

So I try

```
document.write('<iframe src='+ location.href + ' width="468" height="60" ></iframe>');
```

But it seems not to be working at chrome...

This also does not work

```
<div id="main"></div>
function $(id)
{
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
  var div = document.createElement("iframe");
div.setAttribute("src", location.href);
div.setAttribute("width", "500");
div.setAttribute("height", "90");
$('main').appendChild(div); 
document.write(location.href);
```

And this does not work

```
function $(id)
{
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
document.write('<div id="main"></div>');
  var div = document.createElement("iframe");
div.setAttribute("src", location.href);
div.setAttribute("width", "500");
div.setAttribute("height", "90");
$('main').appendChild(div); 
document.write(location.href);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <iframe src="about:blank" onload="if(!this.t){this.t=1; var href=location.href.replace(/[\?\&]inf\=.+/i,''); href += href.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&inf=' : '?inf='; this.src = href + Math.random();}"></iframe>
```

I tried on chrome.. seems ok :)

**Edit**

appended some regex for safe url

Answer (score 2):

Looks like most browsers block that option, which is probably a good idea.

Tested with the code:

```
<iframe src="."></iframe>
```

On Chrome, I get this page:
[image]

http://jsbin.com/epimi4/